# Way to stop the bot safely

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been working in a discord bot and I have a little problem with it. The only way I'm able to stop it is using CTRL+C which I don't think it's a safe way to do it because I always get some errors thrown when doing so

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0xb4c6f3a0>
Exception ignored in: <function ClientResponse.__del__ at 0xb6fb6ec8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 757, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 177, in release
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 629, in _release
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 62, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 692, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Any information on how should I stop the bot without these errors would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
try:
    #whole code here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting")
    await client.logout()
```

When you press <kbd>Control - C</kbd>, it triggers the error [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt). If you catch this with a [`try and accept block`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), you can safely exit the program.

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, what you are trying to achieve is to have a way to exit your program and not let it run forever.

To do this, you can either handle `KeyboardInterrupt` to exit the code,

```
try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Interrupted'
    sys.exit(0)
```

Or you should find some logic in your code after which you can terminate the program, so something like a if condition, which when met you just call `sys.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

make a command called `shutdown`

```
@client.command(name="shutdown")
async def shut_down():
    print("logging out...")
    await client.logout()
```

now try to close the program:)